# Add a UITextField to a UITableView on a button click

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

After quite a long time perusing the web i have decided to come here as i usually have my questions answered super speedy and super well on Stack Overflow!

I am attempting to complete the following and would be grateful of any suggestions or pointers in the right direction:

- Display a UITableView
- When a "+" button is pressed a UITextField is added to a row of the UITableView
- The user can type a string into this field
- If the user selects the "+" Button again another UITextfield is added to the next row. (You get the idea)
- When the user is done adding UITextFields and filling them in they can hit a "Save" button at which point all entries in each row are saved to an array.

Any suggestions regarding this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pseudocode might be a starting point:

```
// define an NSMutableArray called fields

- (IBAction)addField:(id)sender {
    // create a new text field here and add it to the array
    // then reload data
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    for(UITextField *textField in fields) {
        // whatever you have to do
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // you have as many rows as textfields
    return [fields count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    // For row N, you add the textfield N to the array.
    [cell addSubview:(UITextField *)[fields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys.. i know that was a little vague ... but his has really helped and i am well on my way.  Thank you

Comment: I feel like you'd rather calling `cell addSubview` inside the `if (cell==nil)` block so you don't add it every time the cell gets reused.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4**

Instead of reloading the whole table you can use beginUpdate and endUpdate here.

Add target to the cell button(You can use view tag or create new TableviewCell class).

```
    cell.addBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addTextField(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell.txtField.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then implement this method:

```
@objc func addTextField(_ sender:UIButton) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

    if let cell = tblView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableCell {
        tblArray.append(cell.txtField.text!)
    }

    let newRow = IndexPath(row: sender.tag + 1, section: 0)
    tblView.beginUpdates()
    tblView.insertRows(at: [newRow], with: .left) 
    tblView.endUpdates()
}
```

Do not forget to put        `var tblArray:[Any] = [""]` at start.

Hope this anyone who is looking for Swift answer.

Happy coding.